# phpMyAdmin "Create database: Documentation No Privileges", how to create database?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm just starting to learn php and mysql, and just trying to set everything up. To try out example problems for learning, I'm trying to create database by logging into the http:://my-local-ip/phpmyadmin/. I can login using the user-name and password used during installation, but trying to cretae database I see `No Privileges`.

I have looked at the possible duplicates, I have tried clearing cache/cookies and entering flush and the user command sql, they have not fixed my issue.

Note that, I'm not on the same computer, I have a separate computer that I'm ssh-ing into (both ubuntu 16) and I'm accessing the web-phpMyAdmin via the local ip address of the ssh-ed computer.

I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you login to mysql via the CLI?

Comment: @wogsland I'm not sure how that works. I have tried: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'; -- which did ran without error

Comment: Ah, have you tried logging in to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`rather than `http://my-local-ip/phpmyadmin/`? Because `my-local-ip` won't be a place root has login privileges unless you've set that up.

Comment: @wogsland thanks for the info, I'll try that, though I'll need to get a monitor there, I was trying to learn by simulating a sort of real server with no monitor and such. How is that normally done in real/production servers ?

Comment: You just need to grant privileges to the user (preferablely not root for security reasons) at whatever ip you intend to access mysql from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solved my issue, on ssh-ed terminal, I ran:
`sudo mysql`
and on the prompt:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myUsernameCreatedEarlier'@'localhost';
```

Then I cleared the cache/cookies on the browser on my computer (not the server computer). And logged in on the phpMyAdmin web portal. Now I have database creation access.

Comment: Worked for me.  All the advice from other people about using root and etc didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands for mariadb with phpmyadmin:

```
sudo mariadb

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';
```